# Function app run every saterday at 01:00 faliing

Tags: azure-functions

I have a function app with following cron expression I want to run every saterday at 01:00:

'0 0 1 ? * 5 *'

However I got following error.

The schedule expression '0 0 1 ? * 5 *' was not recognized as a valid cron expression

I tried different online cron expression builders. According to the documentation:"For days, the numeric values are 0 to 6 where 0 starts with Sunday." When I look on the general documentation for cron it looks like 0 i monday. I also tried '0 0 1 ? * SAT *'. What is the right cron exprssion for function apps to run every saterday at 01:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below one:

{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}
  0         0        1     *      *       6